# Django, remove the querystring from a url string

Tags: django

Good day all.
I've to modify a string in a template that use Django.
the string is a URL, but this can contain a querystring, so basically the url could be:

```
"www.test.com/something" or
"www.test.com/something?page=2"
```

I'd like to remove the "?page=2" from the url, in javascript I'd do something like

```
urlString.split("?")[0];
```

is there any similar solution in django?
I can only access the "frontend" of this site, so I cannot define anything, I can only modify the "templates".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, as far as django is actually not a language,n but a python framework. The front side language will remain javascript, or you will need to access the back end to update the related view using python

Comment: ok thanks, this is leading me to the right road, sorry for the very noob question, but this is the very first time I saw some django code (and I recognize it by trying to search some code patterns on G)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With python (Django is Python) it's nearly the same syntax.

Just without the semicolon at line end.

The variable name urlString could also be used but its a soft standard to write snake cased object variables.

```py
url_string = 'www.test.com/something'
url_string.split('?')[0]


url_string = 'www.test.com/something?page=2'
url_string.split('?')[0]
```

Comment: oh, ok, thanks seems promising, I'll try it asap